# couchdb sorting and count

Tags: couchdb

I'am trying to get some statistic in couchDB. Structure of documents is

```
[{
    _id: "1",
    name: "Hotel A",
    type: "hotel",
    stars: 3,
    flags: ["family-friendly","pet-friendly","green-hotel","sport"],
    hotelType: "premium",
    food: ["breakfast","lunch"]
}, {
    _id: "2",
    name: "Hotel B",
    type: "hotel",
    stars: 4,
    flags: ["family-friendly","pet-friendly"],
    hotelType: "budget",
    food: ["breakfast"]
}, {
    _id: "3",
    name: "Hotel C",
    type: "hotel",
    stars: 5,
    flags: ["family-friendly","pet-friendly"],
    hotelType: "budget",
    food: ["breakfast","lunch","dinner"]
}]
```

How can I get how much hotels have a "breakfast", "lunch", "dinner" and sort it? I would like to get an answer like this

```
{{breakfast:3},{lunch:2},{dinner:1}
```

}

or something like that.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are supposed to describe what you tried first. Here is a hint: your `map` function will create an index with **each** food item as a `key`, and your `reduce` function will **count** rows for each `group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest thing to do is use a map function which emits, for each document, the set of `food` items in that document:

```
function (doc) {
  doc.food.forEach(function (item) {
    emit(iten, null)});
}
```

Each key in the index is now just a food item.  You'll have one key for each hotel and food item.  So far it looks a bit chatty:

```
$ curl -s 'http://localhost:5984/hotels/_design/so/_view/foods?reduce=false'
{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"1","key":"breakfast","value":null},
{"id":"2","key":"breakfast","value":null},
{"id":"3","key":"breakfast","value":null},
{"id":"3","key":"dinner","value":null},
{"id":"1","key":"lunch","value":null},
{"id":"3","key":"lunch","value":null}
]}
```

But we can get couchdb to add up all the keys for us by using a reduce step.  Counting each item is such a common task that it's got a special erlang implementation, just use "`_count`" for your reduce function, and then, when using the view, use `group=true` to tell it to perform the reduction step separately for each distinct key.

```
$ curl -s 'http://localhost:5984/hotels/_design/so/_view/foods?group=true'
{"rows":[
{"key":"breakfast","value":3},
{"key":"dinner","value":1},
{"key":"lunch","value":2}
]}
```

Comment: @user2898796: if you found my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking on the checkbox